# OS on secondary hard drive not detected in ubuntu

Tags: windows, bios

I have a dual boot system with windows os installed on ssd and entire ubuntu installation on hdd. Ubuntu is not detecting the windows os present on the ssd. The grub menu only shows ubuntu and the whole ssd drive cannot be detected from gparted. I can boot ubuntu or windows both from the BIOS menu. I want to add the windows option also in the grub menu. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows 7 doesn't show in boot menu after installing GRUB and Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/245599/windows-7-doesnt-show-in-boot-menu-after-installing-grub-and-ubuntu)

Comment: @karel i think the root of the problem may be that my ssd is using RAID 0 and ubuntu doesn't read RAID. One option will be changing it to AHCI. Also, I don't want to install windows again, so currently I am just booting ubuntu through BIOS